# form input text with JQUERY validation failing

Tags: jquery, validation

Okay, I have the following jQuery code but I am not sure where I am getting it wrong. I tried to validate an individual text input. can someone improve the code. :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count = 0;

 $(cellphone).keyup(function(){

   var regEx =/[1-9 ]/;
   count = count + 1;
   var Str = $('#cellphone').val();

if(!regEx.test(Str)){
    $("#msg").text("Phone number format invalid");
    }

if(count>11){

    //alert("Cellphone number invalid, please check");

    $("#msg").text("Phone number Invalid");
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: On line number 4 it should be `#cellphone`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dude, Don't go for the hardest thing
Use Validate Plugin for Validation
Example:
$( "#myform" ).validate({
rules: {
 'field_name': {
  required: true,  
 minlength:10
  maxlength: 10
},
messages: {
'field_name': {
  required: 'Required',
  minlength: 'Length is Lesser than 10',
  maxlength: 'Length exceeds Greater than 10'
}
```

}
      });
    [Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/maxlength-method/)

Comment: Thanks that worked quite nicelly. I am new to the library so I am still finding my feet. Thanks Nanda